# Axios request multiselect unable value to change in update form as PUT Method; React.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend, web-frontend

This is form of update which has select for multiselect but uable to get stored data change as select and deselect for it.

**code.**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select'
import {
    CPagination,
    CCard,
    CCardBody,
    CCardHeader,
    CCol,
    CDataTable,
    CRow,
    CNavbarNav,
    CForm,
    CInput, CNavbar,
    CButton, CContainer, CFormGroup, CCardFooter, CLabel, CSelect
} from '@coreui/react';
import CIcon from '@coreui/icons-react'
import {useCookies} from 'react-cookie';
import API_SERVICE from 'src/views/API/API_Service';

function Form(records) {
    const [name, setName]  = useState('
    const [newspaper_of, setNewspaper_of] = useState('')
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [token] = useCookies(['mytoken'])

    useEffect(() => {
        setName(records.list.name)
        setNewspaper_of(records.list.newspaper_of)
    }, [])
   
// send to update data PUT method ...
    const Update_list = () =>{
        API_SERVICE.updateforCustomer(records.list.id, {name,newspaper_of},token['mytoken'])
            .then(res => records.updateinfor(res))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
    
    //   for get data to select dropdown
    
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getCharacters() {
          const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Newspaper/",{
            'method': 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                'Authorization' : 'Token afd6dc50d52e47f5dfc29b5d9e027660e400196c',
            }
          });
          const body = await response.json();
        setItems(body.map(({ newspaper,id }) => ({ label: newspaper, value: id })));
        }
       
       getCharacters();
       
      }, []);
   
   

    function handleChange(event){
        setNewspaper_of(event)
    }

    return (
        <div>
           
            {records.list ? (

                <div>
                    <CCol xs="12">
                        <CCard>
                            <CCardHeader>
                                <h4><strong> ALTER FORM </strong></h4>
                                {/* <small> Form</small> */}
                            </CCardHeader>
                    <CCardBody>
                    <CFormGroup row>
                        <CCol xs="4">
                    <CLabel htmlFor="company">Newspaper</CLabel>
                    This is have for multi select {/* <CSelect custom name="ccyear" value={newspaper_of} id='language' onChange={e => setNewspaper_of(e.target.value)}   onChange={e => setNewspaper_of(e.target.value)}  custom isMulti>  setNewspaper_of(console.log(e,"E"),e.target.value) } */}
                    
                    <Select custom name="ccyear" value={newspaper_of} id='language'   onChange={handleChange}  isMulti/>
                    {items.map(({ label, value }) => (<option key={value} value={value}  >{label}</option>))} 
                  </Select>

                     {/*==============================================================================================================  */}
                    <CInput id="company" name="name" value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter Newspaper" />

                   

                    
                       </CCol>
                    </CFormGroup>
                    <br></br>
                                         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    {records.list.id ? <CButton type="submit" size="sm" color="primary" onClick={Update_list}>Update</CButton> : <CButton type="submit" size="sm" color="primary" >Add new</CButton>}
                    </CCardBody>
                    </CCard></CCol>

                </div>
            ) : null}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Form
```

The Update form; store data unable to change deselect and select error raise in **multi select**; I want to for multi select is option dynamic and get from axios request fetch data for as option has to **select** item of data as well **deselect** has do via update; for rectify do give the support; **thanks you.**
[image: The Update form; store data unable to change deselect and select error raise]

Answer (score 0):

```
<Select custom name="ccyear" value={ items.filter( i => newspaper_of.some( n => n === i.value ) ) }onChange={(v) => setNewspaper_of(( v || [] ).map( v => v.value) )} isMulti options={ items} />
```

Multiselect  PUT work fine